# Why do i keep getting index out of range

Tags: python

I'm working through the checkio site and have encountered a problem that I don't understand. The input is an array of ones and zero's plus 2 co ordinates. I need to write a function to return how many ones are in a circle to my co ordinates, not counting the one I'm on. I keep getting index out of range, which it is but I thought the 'try:  except index error: ' bit of my code would ignore it and move onto the next iterable. It works with the other examples the site gives, which do have other places where I'm out of range but the code skips it and moves on. Just the last test that fails and I cant figure it out. I've had a good search and can't see the problem. At first I had the 'try' inside the 'for' loop but it wasn't getting that far. I felt like the except should be inside the for loop but every example i've seen its on the same level as the 'try' If you help me you are mega cool. :)  Here's the code with the example i'm getting stuck at.

```
def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):

    count = 0
    a = row - 1
    b = row + 1
    c = col - 1
    d = col + 1
    order = [grid[a][c], grid[a][col], grid[a][d],
             grid[row][c], grid[row][d],
             grid[b][c], grid[b][col], grid[b][d]]

    try:
        for z in order:
            count += z
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return count


count_neighbours(((1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1)), 0, 2)
```

Comment: Someone who puts `try` outside of the `for` loop is simply looking for a different result from someone who puts it inside the loop.  One way is not better than the other; it just comes up with different results.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are on any edge you are trying to look past the edge at locations which don't exist.

For example, checking the neighbors of cell [0,0] in the array you are going to try look at cell [-1,-1] (using `grid[a][c]`) which is an *index* which is "out of range" (not between 0 and the size of the array).  This will happen every time you are on the top or bottom row and the left or rightmost column.  You need to guard against these special conditions.

i.e.

```
for z in order:
    if z >= 0 and z <= length:
       count += z
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the reply.. You've helped me realize that when I had -1 it was counting back so still giving me a result(but the wrong one) it was only when I was on the far right or bottom of the grid that it was giving me out of range so I have to make a new orders list that's in range before implementing it. Thanks for taking the time with such noob stuff. I still dont get why it didn't skip to the next iteration when out of range. Was I using the 'try''except' bit wrongly?

Comment: the way your `try` is set up, an exception will jump out of the entire loop (to the `except`).  You would need to nest the `try` inside the `for` in order to just skip only the current iteration.

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't really be used this way however, they are for exceptional circumstances, not normal running of a program.  You should just guard against the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexError exception is not raised by the for loop but by the initialisation of the order list, you are sometime trying to access the values that are not in the grid (negative indices or > than the size of the grid or > than the size of the tuples stored in the grid).

One solution could be the storage of the indices rather than the values, like this:

```py
def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):

    count = 0
    a = row - 1
    b = row + 1
    c = col - 1
    d = col + 1

    orders = [(a, c), (a, col), (a, d),
    (row, c), (row, d),
    (b, c), (b, col), (b, d)]

    try:
        for x, y in orders:
            count += grid[x][y]
    except IndexError:
        pass

    return count


count_neighbours(((1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1)), 0, 2)
```

Comment: This code didn't work either but i used your suggestion of order = [(a, c...etc and @Ross 's suggestion to build a new list using for x, y in order:
        if (x < 0 or y < 0) or (x >= len(grid) or y >= len(grid[0])):
            pass
        else:
            order2.append((x, y))  and it sorted me out. Without this site I'd be lost as the python docs are double dutch when your a newbie. :)

Comment: In general the functionalities are well documented, but yes, when you start it could be a little bit complicated :) ! Nice job :) !